# include different navigations in php

Tags: php, if-statement, include, navbar

this is my first question here and my problem is that I want to display two different navigation headers depending on if you're logged in or not. I am confused as to why this goes into the if-statement and displays "you are logged in."

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   echo "you are logged in.";
}
```

... but if I use this piece of code at the start of my page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    include 'navbar-other.php';
}
else {
    include 'navbar.php';
}
```

It goes into the else case instead and displays navbar.php rather than navbar-other.php.
This all implies that I am logged in and the $_SESSION variable is getting processed due to the first if-statement giving the desired output. 
Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you included `session_start()` at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Yes, I put it at the beginning of both the navbars

Comment: But did you do it here where you're trying to use them? You need to call it in every place where you use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Okay, this comment really helped! I expected the `session_start()` call to work from the navbar includes, but after writing my second code example with `session_start()` ontop of it at the beginning of each page, it actually works as desired! I thought I could work around having so much duplicated code but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the thing is session needs to be started before you try to use the variable, that's why it couldn't work from the includes. You probably don't need to start the session in the includes themselves. And you're welcome.